# UIButton click to Swap two labels text using Swift?

Tags: swift

I am trying to achieve single `UIButton` click to `Swap` two label text. Here, `label` text need to change routinely for every UIButton click. How to achieve this?

```
@IBOutlet weak var sourceLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var targetLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func swapClick(_ sender: Any) {

        // MARK - Logics Here For Swap
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@IBAction func swapClick(_ sender: Any) {
    (sourceLabel.text, targetLabel.text) = (targetLabel.text, sourceLabel.text)
}
```

Swapping is easier in Swift with tuples. No need to create a temporary variable.

```
var string1 = "a"
var string2 = "b"
func swap(_ str1: inout String, _ str2: inout String) {
  (str1, str2) = (str2, str1)
}
swap(&string1, &string2)
print(string1)//b
print(string2)//a
```

Comment: Now that's clever.